# What's the deal with Orochimaru and seals?

Tags: naruto

During the chunin exams, when Orochimaru attacked Konoha, the Third Hokage managed to seal the hands of Orochimaru, rendering him incapable of using any jutsus.

But later in the series we see that Orochimaru did use jutsus. For eg, during the battle with Naruto he uses the Kawarimi no Jutsu.

Though it has not been depicted that he uses hand seals to perform Kawarimi no Jutsu, but I presume that a jutsu of that level needs a hand seal to be pulled off. 
So, Orochimaru had never lost his jutsus.

Next, Sasuke managed to absorb Orochimaru into his body which was sealed off by Itachi using the sealing powers of Sword of Totsuka. How then is it possible for Orochimaru to be present in someone else's body and "pop out at will".

So how is it that no sealing techniques work upon Orochimaru?

[How Orochimaru resurrected the 4 Hokages.](http://www.mangareader.net/naruto/618/15)

Answer (score 2):

There was only a part of Orochimaru that was in Sasuke's body. I believe that the curse mark transfers a part of his chakra and thus a part of himself into the body of the target.

It was the part of Orochimaru that was inside Sasuke that was sealed away by Itachi using the sealing powers of Sword of Totsuka. But a part of him still lived inside the others who carried the curse mark and his chakra was there with Kabuto, who absorbed Orochimaru after Sasuke killed his main body.

Remember that Orochimaru was very weak when Sasuke revived him that he had to absorb his chakra from Kabuto to become somewhat normal again.

---

And it is not true that Orochimaru couldn't be sealed.The 3rd Hokage couldn't seal him just because he was too weak by then to pull Orochimaru with him. And it is not that Orochimaru can pop-out at will from anyone's body. Sasuke resurrected him. He didn't pop-out at will.

Comment: This still doesn't explain how Orochimaru was unable to use jutsus in the original naruto series after his hands got sealed, and use jutsus in the Shippuden series. Remember he uses the Sanjū Rashōmon(Triple Rashōmon) during his battle with Naruto

Comment: His hands got sealed by the 3rd  right? So he might have used another body to continue using seals.

Comment: Its confusing, a part of his soul is sealed, but he can utilise it like nothing ever happened?

Comment: Where is it told that a part of his soul is sealed by the 3rd? 3rd failed to seal his soul.

Comment: Wasn't the hands, that was sealed, a part of his soul?? That was the part that was severed by the death reaper just before sealing them off

Comment: @debal: Soul and body are different. Soul is a kind spiritual energy. It has nothing to do with physical body. Remember the Human Path of the sage of six paths/pain. It just absorbs the soul, but the body is not damaged at all.

Comment: So what was it that the death reaper cut off? The death reaper does not seal the physical body, but rather the spiritual body. And that is what the death reaper cut off and sealed in him.

Comment: To clarify that, i do believe death reaper seals the physical body also. Because, one needs the physical dead body of a person to perform Edo Tendsei. But Orochimar ressurected the Hokages by just breaking the reapers stomach. Doesn't that mean the seal takes in the physical body as well? It is said nowhere that the death reaper don't take the physical body. I Orochimaru's case the death reaper maynot have been able to touch his soul but succeeded in making physical damage.
PS: the comments are getting long enough, i think it would be better to take this to a chat if we need to discuss further

Comment: No he did not. Orochimaru used the bodies of the white zetsus to ressurect the 4 hokages

Comment: Edo tensei needs the deadbody as well as another body which is converted into the resurrected person. Orochimaru used the white zetsus as the bodies to transfer their souls into, not instead of dead bodies of Hokages. Using bodies of white zetsus alone, one can only resurrect white zetsu's not the hokages.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT: You only need one victim, one soul, **and some DNA** to activate Edo Tensei, you don't need  the whole body. For example, By the time he was resurrected, Madara's body (heck, Hashirama's body!) would turn into bones, Possibly *dust*.

Comment: Remember how Kabuto resurrected Danzo's body gaurd(I forgot his name). He was killed and his partners body was used to resurrect him.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT please refer to the manga chapter 618, and you'll see that Orochimaru mentions that he indeed has the DNA of the 4 hokages. So your assumption about the Death reaper seal sealing only physical body is wrong. It indeed seals spiritual body. I have included a snapshot of the mange in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Harikrishnan T's answer covers most of it. I'll answer the part of how could he use Jutsu.

Hand seals are a form of technique to focus one's chakra, in order to perform a specific jutsu. As you progress is proficiency and power, you can focus your chakra more and more innately, without the need for hand seals.

The example for this is that Zabuza required more than 40 hand seals to perform the Water Dragon Bullet, while the Second only required one.

---

That's why Orochimaru was able to use the most basic technique without the use of his hands (such as the Replacement Jutsu). As for the rest, I recall Kabuto doing the hand seals for him whenever he required a more advanced jutsu (such as the Summoning Jutsu).

Answer (score 0):

Orochimaru had dedicated himself to the path of Kinjutsu. This means that he is using mostly forbidden jutsu. Because of his endless experimentation on himself to become even more powerful, he moved to a place above natural law.

He's living on a different set of rules than the rest of the ninja world, and so is his village (if there is anything left of it).

He sought immortality so that he could master every jutsu, even the science of creating jutsu.

As for being in different bodies and popping out of them, here is what I've observed from the manga: he infects a person with himself. Look at Kabuto. That was a serious infection. The curse mark is another example. The curse mark is purely a technique developed by Orochimaru, and infects people with his power. Although the level and type of infection in Kabuto vs. Sasuke is inherently different.

He is "above" being sealed because he warped himself into a viral entity, or a "demon" as the 3rd Hokage called him. Even the Nine-Tailed Fox could be sealed because he is a natural force of nature. There is nothing natural about Orochimaru!

Comment: I don't know how accurate this answer is. All of Orochimaru's techniques are well explained, there's nothing unnatural about him. Relatively to the Uchiha, he's actually pretty weak. Also, this answer doesn't seem to answer the question at all. It's all praise for Orochimaru, but there's nothing here that explains how he could perform techniques even though his hands are cursed.

Comment: i agree with @MadaraUchiha. In the Sanin Showdown, kabuto had to perform the jutsus for orochimaru, but later in the shippuden series, Orochimaru could himself perform the actions.